# serial communication with USB device using 'GNET' protocol

Tags: python, usb, pyserial

I have a USB device with the following [specification](http://www.barcode-uk.com/images/Promag%20pcr-MFR%20120u.pdf). Page 22 describes the `GNET protocol` that should be used to interact with the device.

The connection is fine but the device just doesn't give me any response, so I think I am not sending the correct data to it, maybe missing the handshake?

**From Specification**

> Support TTY (TELE TYPE) OPERATION - Use TTY to send commands and messages
>
> Use ASCII value for each field and use Separator "," between two
>    Fields.
>   [image]

**connect_and_send.py**

```
import serial

port = "COM3"
baud = 9600

ser = serial.Serial(port, baud, timeout=1)

if ser.isOpen():
    print(ser.name + ' is open...')

# STX, N, CR
to_send = b'\x02\x4e\x0d'
print "Sending {}".format(to_send)
ser.write(to_send)
out = ser.read()
print('Receiving...'+out)
```

COM3 is the correct port:

[image]

Any help and guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the supplier in the end and the issue was setting to wrong baud rate. Changing from 9600 to 19200 resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have**never​** to use `\x4e`, this is the **Negative Acknowledge**  from the device.
Try

```
to_send = b'\x02F\x0d'
```

to get Firmware Version

Comment: `\x4e` it is negative acknowledge for the reply, the issue is I'm not receiving one.

Comment: @DannyCullen: You only receive something if you send a valid "command". Have you tried "b'\x02F\x0d'", still receiving nothing?

Comment: At one stage it was echoing. Now it's just not replying at all. Yes I have tried a lot of combinations of data to send including your example.

Comment: @DannyCullen: Please remain on this command "b'\x02F\x0d'" in your Answers. It's hard to understand your comments if you telling whats happen else. I ask again: **Did you receive a answer with the command "b'\x02F\x0d'"**?

Comment: This does now indeed return the firmware version number, the baud rate was the issue.